# F6 wont work and only turns brightness up

Tags: shortcut-keys

Hey I was trying to do something that needs me to press F+6 but when I press it it just turns the brightness up and that is not what i want it to do and now I cant do the thing I need to do because of this. I have looked every where and every one is just saying that the brightness key wont work or the brightness wont go up but nothing about what I am having trouble with. (Note im using a Mac keyboard on my pc im using Ubuntu 22.10)

Comment: Which version of MacOS are you using? What happens if you press Fn+F6?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu not Mac I just have a Mac keyboard plugged into my pc

Comment: Ok I edited the text it should be good now should be good now

Comment: yea i tried every thing even a diffrent keyboard nothing worked

Comment: fixed it it is s

Comment: Could you write an answer below by clicking **Answer Your Own Question** below?